# Where to find LED values of the Raspberry Pi Pico MicroPython Learning Kit?

Tags: led, pi-pico, voltage, current

I am getting started with a pico and I got the Raspberry Pi Pico MicroPython Learning Kit from waveshare (https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-pico-micropython-learning-kit-pico-included)

It includes 3 LEDs but it just says 5mm LED, there is no info on the voltage drop or the proper current. I looked around online and found information on other LEDs which basically always want 20mA with a voltage drop of 2V. However, sometimes I also find a voltage drop of 3.2 - 3.6. Most websites also talk about different values for each color.

Is there a specsheet online somewhere? I just cannot find it and even the waveshare website doesn't have more info. Or is there some other way to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it.

As Joan has said voltage depends on colour and LED technology but provided it is lower than the Pico output (3.3V) is not critical; after more than 55 years as an engineer I just grab a resistor and vary to appropriate brightness.

The Pico can safely supply 50mA total & a maximum of 16mA per pin; 8mA is typical.

At a rough guess I would suggest you use one of the resistors supplied. It is not clear from the picture but they look like 470 which is the value I normally use.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably thousands of types of LEDs.

If you want to know the characteristics of yours you need to ask Waveshare or perhaps Pi Hut.

Voltage drop typically depends on the LED colour.

The LEDs I use tend to only need a milliamp or so to be bright.  20 milliamps sounds excessive.